# Join data as different row from 3 different tables when structure are different and data are different

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to `sql`, and been given a task to join 3 tables. Could someone please shed some light on this `sql`.

I have 3 tables, like 
Table 1

```
userID | username | password
 1        user1      user1
 2        user2      user2
```

table 2

```
userID | order number | order quantity
2           101             100
```

table 3

```
userID | name | address
1        John    xxx
2        Will    xxx
3        Peter   xxx
```

And the result table needs to be displayed as:

```
UserID | username | name | address | order number | order quantity        
1         user1     John    xxxxx      0               0
2         user2     Will    xxxxx      101           100
3         user3     Peter   xxxxx      0               0
```

Comment: where's the SQL you have come up with so far?

Comment: You need to pick up a SQL book.

Comment: Mysql website has great documentation with few examples. It can take time to figure out but next time you will not ask help and see how simple it is. Simply joining 3 table not different than 2 table. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check out http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to see tips and hints on how to improve your question. In this case: it's always appreciated if you add your own efforts to the question. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE` on some columns,

```
SELECT  a.`userid`,
        a.`username`,
        c.`name`,
        c.`address`,
        COALESCE(b.`order number`, 0) `order Number`,
        COALESCE(b.`order quantity`, 0) `order quantity`
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            on a.userid = b.userid
        LEFT JOIN table3 c
            on a.userid = c.userid
```

Basically, what `LEFT JOIN` does is to retrieve all rows from the left table whether it has a match on the second table or not. `COALESCE` handles what `null` values should be looked like.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you so much for this. I think the reason why it didn't give me the right result was cause I was using INNER JOIN.

Comment: Inner join and outer joins are two different things. Inner join retrieves records that are present on both tables while outer join like left join retrieves all records from the left table wheter it has a match on the other table or not.

Comment: Hi John, I have tried different things, but it seems like the the end result always has the same data for all the rows.   I have also tried group by command, but it fixed the last column, then the 3 column became all the same. Not sure if I am making any sense.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
select 
    a.userID, 
    c.name, 
    c.address, 
    b.order_number, 
    b.order_quantity 
from 
    table1 a 
        join table3 c 
            on a.userID=c.userID 
        join table2 b 
            on a.userID=c.userID
```

However, you might need to pick up a SQL book as this is a very simple thing to do.

Comment: hello @Sam, this join will work but not basically answers the question. The reason is it will not show records whose user id does not exist on either tables or both. So in your query, it will only return records for `2        user2      user2`

Comment: @JohnWoo, you are quite right; I didn't pay attention to the data in the tables.